# WinSCP folder sorting

Tags: sorting, winscp

How can I "sort" folders in WinSCP?

For now it looks like this:

[image]

but I want folders to be on bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can use file panel and sort based on many conditions. If you want first folder shoen and then file you need sort based on type
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_file_panel

Comment: Worked, i turned on tree more and disabled directories by filter, Thanks!

Comment: @KaspianSmoliński So you used a completely different solution than proposed in this answer. Consider posting your own answer then.